# PHP underscore in filename variable?

Tags: php

Why is there an underscore for data_?

Is there a simpler way of writing this, so that it makes more sense in terms of code readability?

My analysis:

data_ is supposed to take whatever data_ is, request a message via the variable `postmessage` from the form and make sure it's text and concatenate all this:

```
 $filename = 'data_'.$_REQUEST['postmessage'].'.txt';
```

I am a beginner and my analysis of this code could be wrong, but I am willing to learn from my mistakes.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here. Do you want to perform I/O operations on a file specified from a form?

Comment: FWIW I think it is a good question.

Comment: +1 above to negate whoever downvoted the question. It is a valid technical question. Not sure why anyone would downvote it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's break it down a bit:

1. **$filename =** - assigning a value into a variable called `$filename`.
2. **data_** - just a string.
3. **$_REQUEST['postmessage']** - the value of the **postmessage** request parameter (could be either POST, GET or a COOKIE parameter. Try not using `$_REQUEST` too often, unless you absolutely have to. Use `$_GET` or `$_POST` instead). This would come from your form (as you've mentioned).
4. **.'.txt'** - just a string.

A dot between the elements above is used to concatenate the strings.

About your comment "and make sure it's text" - wrong. It doesn't make sure it's text. You need to make sure of that yourself and you probably should (for security reasons).

Comment: Thank you for breaking it down a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're just sequencing a string in this code.

The . is a concatenation operator.

So $filename would contain

```
data_somethingorother.txt
```

The underscore is part of the string you're constructing.

Answer (score 1):

It's part of the filename. Don't ask us why the name of the file contains it...
Just take care, it's not safe not to validate what comes in `$_REQUEST['postmessage']` before using its value.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want. Let's say `$_REQUEST['postmessage']` contains `"foo"`. The first example will produce `$filename = 'data_foo.txt'`, <strike>while the second one will produce `$filename = 'data.txtfoo'`.</strike> (OP removed second example from question)

I'd guess the first one is the desired outcome, but that depends on your needs. It's just string concatenation, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

With regard to readability, I'd suggest to surround the string concatenation operator `.` with spaces. Thus, something like:

```
$filename = 'data_' . $_REQUEST['postmessage'] . '.txt';
```

Using a text editor / IDE with PHP-targeted syntax highlighting may also help a lot. A basic PHP tutorial will also do so.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, it's just constructing a filename from a GET/POST variable. As far as readability, I think it's fine.

However, you need to be very careful when using GET/POST variables, or anything that a user can change, to construct file paths. I would almost always say you shouldn't do it at all. If you're going to, at least make sure they can't do things like `postmessage=../../filename`.

Answer (score 0):

Ditto,

However, I'd define a variable to store the request variable. It makes your code easier to read, therefore easier to debug. It will also make performing sanitization cleaner.

`$postMessage = $_REQUEST['postmessage'];
$filename = 'data_' . $postMessage . '.txt';`